# Custom creation of QFuture

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I've faced quite an odd problem with `QtConcurrent`, mostly because of strange programming desires, maybe it's just an XY-problem, but...

So, there is my code, trying to communicate with the database, a backend code actually (on Qt, yes). It has to work quick and handle some requests, so I need a thread pool. As a well-known fact I suppose the connection establishing itself is a very time-consuming operation, so there is a need in persistent database connections resulting in persistent threads (`QSqlDatabase` cannot be moved around between the threads). Also it is quite natural to want asynchronous request handling, thus resulting in some need of a simple way to pass them to the persistent threads.

Nothing too complex, lets assume there already exists some boilerplate in a form like...

```cpp
// That's what I want for now
QFuture<int> res = workers[i]->async(param1, param2);

// OR

// That's what I DO NOT want to get
workers[i]->async(param1, param2, [](QFuture<int> res) { // QFuture to pass exceptions
     // callback here
});
```

That can be done for sure. Why not `std::future`? Well, it is much easier to use `QFutureWatcher` and it's signals for notifications about result's readiness. Pure C++ notification solutions are *muuuch* more complex and callbacks are also someting that has to be dragged through the class hierarchy. Each worker interfaces a thread with DB connections, obviously.

Okay, all of that can be written, but... custom thread pool would mean no `QtConcurrent` convenience, there seem to be only risky ways to create that `QFuture` so that it could be returned by the custom worker. `QThreadPool` is of no use, because it would be a whole big story to create persistent runnables in it. More to say, the boilerplate I've briefly described is gonna be some kind of project's core, used in many places, not something to be easily replaced by a 100 hand-made thread managings.

In short: if I could construst a `QFuture` for my results, the problem would be solved. 
Could anyone point me to a solution or a workaround? Would be grateful for any bright ideas.

---

**UPD:**

@VladimirBershov offered a good modern solution which implements observer pattern. After some googling I've found a [QPromise](https://github.com/simonbrunel/qtpromise) library. Of course, constructing a custom `QFuture` is still hacky and can be only done via undocumented `QFutureInterface` class, but still some  "promise-like" solution makes asynchronous calls neater by far as I can judge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AsyncFuture](https://github.com/benlau/asyncfuture) library as a custom `QFuture` creation tool or ideas source:

> AsyncFuture - Use QFuture like a Promise object
>
> QFuture is used together with QtConcurrent to represent the result of
>   an asynchronous computation. It is a powerful component for
>   multi-thread programming. But its usage is limited to the result of
>   threads, it doesn't work with the asynchronous signal emitted by
>   QObject. And it is a bit trouble to setup the listener function via
>   QFutureWatcher.
>
> AsyncFuture is designed to enhance the function to offer a better way
>   to use it for asynchronous programming. It provides a Promise object
>   like interface. This project is inspired by AsynQt and RxCpp.

**Features:**

> - Convert a signal from QObject into a QFuture object
> - Combine multiple futures with different type into a single future object
> - Use Future like a Promise object
> - Chainable Callback - Advanced multi-threading programming model

**Convert a signal from QObject into a QFuture object:**

```
#include "asyncfuture.h"
using namespace AsyncFuture;

// Convert a signal from QObject into a QFuture object

QFuture<void> future = observe(timer, &QTimer::timeout).future();

/* Listen from the future without using QFutureWatcher<T>*/
observe(future).subscribe([]() {
    // onCompleted. It is invoked when the observed future is finished successfully
    qDebug() << "onCompleted";
},[]() {
    // onCanceled
    qDebug() << "onCancel";
});
```

Comment: That's it! I've even found it's more sophisticated analogue in Qt Store. Hopefully should work in my case =)

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to use thread pools with maximum 1 thread available for each.

```
QThreadPool* persistentThread = new QThreadPool; // no need to write custom thread pool
persistentThread->setMaxThreadCount(1);
persistentThread->setExpiryTimeout(-1);
```

and then

```
QFuture<int> future_1 = QtConcurrent::run(persistentThread, func_1);
QFuture<int> future_2 = QtConcurrent::run(persistentThread, func_2);
```

`func_2` will be executed after `func_1` in the same one "persistent" thread.

Comment: Thanks! But... 1) `QtConcurrent::run` is a "shoot-and-forget" method, there is just no way I could have a permanently open db connection, after `run` finishes there is no place for it to be stored 2) The solution is a nice hack but having several workers that way would look _waaay_ too dirty =((